# Combine to open different Forms with parameter

Tags: c#

How can I write this code to one function?
I need this on several points and I think it's not good to write it all the time - cause of changes ...
The only difference is the Formname.

```
if (language == "english")
{
    FormEng eng = new FormEng();
    eng.DeliveryId = iDelId;
    eng.CustomerId = iCustomerId;
    eng.Year = iYear;
    eng.Show();
}
else if (language == "german")
{
    FormGer ger = new FormGer();
    ger.DeliveryId = iDelId;
    ger.CustomerId = iCustomerId;
    ger.Year = iYear;
    ger.Show();
}
```

Comment: if you're trying to figure out how localization works, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y99d1cd3(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 1):

That is not the right approach to make a multi language application. You should really use language resources for that. Here is a long article that will lead you through all the process:

https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/580043/How-to-make-a-multi-language-application-in-Csharp

Comment: It is not a multi language application. That's only to choose the right report to the user (the report viewer is on the form).

Comment: Basically, FormEng and FormGer are the same form with different language?

Comment: Actually I have two forms. Diffent name an one form with the english .rdlc and one with german. But I can use one form if it's possible to choose different .rdlc on one form

Answer (score 0):

Define base class `FormAny` with common members as `DeliveryId`, `CustomerId`. Then define derived classes `FormEng : FormAny` and `FormGer : FormAny`. The above can be modified to:

```
FormAny f = null;
switch (language)
{
    case "english": f = new FormEng(); break;
    case "german": f = new FormGer(); break;
}
f.DeliveryId = iDelId;
f.CustomerId = iCustomerId;
f.Year = iYear;
f.Show();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make an interface or parent class that your forms implement/derive from. Something like this:

```
public abstract class ParentForm : Form
{
    public int DeliveryId { get; set; }
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public int Year { get; set; }
}

public class FormEng : ParentForm
{
}

public class FormGer : ParentForm
{
}
```

Then to use it, you'd do this:

```
ParentForm form;
if (language == "english")
    form = new FormEng();
else
    form = new FormGer();

form.DeliveryId = iDelId;
form.CustomerId = iCustomerId;
form.Year = iYear;
form.Show();
```